# .NET/MVC4/Jquery Mobile/Knockout/Chrome/iPhone extra # character in URL

Tags: ios, asp.net-mvc, jquery-mobile, knockout.js

Okay, if I could offer a bounty for this I would - I offer virtual karma.

As mentioned in the title I have an .NET/MVC4/Jquery Mobile/Knockout website.  On the index page there is a button

```
<button data-bind="click: getResults" data-theme="f">Search</button>
```

which calls a javascript function

```
$.mobile.navigate("/results?option1=a&option2=b", { transition: amw.transitions.slide });
```

This works great on all browsers and devices except Chrome/iPhone.  As far as I can tell the version of Chrome or iOS does not matter. The resulting URL in the address bar is

iPhone/Chrome: http://www.mywebsite.com/**#**/results?option1=a&option2=b

Other Devices: http://www.mywebsite.com/results?option1=a&option2=b

I have put alerts throughout jQuery mobile to try and figure out what is going on (if someone knows a way to debug chrome on iOS let me know) and I cannot see where the extra # is being added.

This may not seem like a big deal but the url ends up being passed on to a downstream service that really does not like the extra #.

I can put in a hack at the call to the service to strip out the # but I would really like to figure out what is happening.

The only suspect line I can find in jQuery mobile (1.3.0) is line #2298

```
// if the hash is included in the data make sure the shape
// is consistent for comparison
if( data.hash && data.hash.indexOf( "#" ) === -1) {
    data.hash = "#" + data.hash;
}
```

But I am not sure what this does or why it would occour only on Chrome/iPhone.

so StackOverflow people - what is going on?

Thanks.

Comment: The `data-bind` attribute on the `button` is missing a closing quote- not sure if that is a typo or if it might be causing problems.

Comment: Good, catch.  Yes it's a type and I have updated the question

Comment: I can tell you that the hash is used by JQM for navigation purposes: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/page-navmodel.html This allows you to bookmark different "pages" within your single-page application. I can't tell you why you have different behaviour between different devices, however.

Comment: Thanks Chris, yes I understand the use of the # tag for JQM navigation - I am just stumped as to why it only shows up for Chrome/iOS